# Combine Tables with doppel Key in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two Datasets and want to add Columns from DATA2 to DATA1 by using doppel Key.

Problem:
Data1 is having more rows than DATA2.

I want R to copy all values with the right doppel key.
Ich habe 2 Datensätze die ich nach Zwei Spalten ergänzend zusammenfügen möchte. Jedoch hat DATA1 mehr Zeilen (mehrfach nennung gleicher Zeilen) als DATA 2.

What i have:

```
    DATA1                    DATA2
    key1  key 2 ...           key1  key2   XXX
    A     1                   A     1       X
    A     1                   A     2       Y
    A     2                   B     1       Z
    B     1                   
    B     1
    B     1
    .
```

Mein Ziel ist es DATA1 um die Spalten XXX zu ergänzen.
Die Werte XXX von DATA 2 sollen in den häufigeren Zeilen von DATA1 kopiert werde bzw. mehrfach genannt werden.

What i need:

```
DATA 1                    DATA2
key1  key 2  WERTE        key1  key2  WERTE
A     1       X            A     1       X
A     1       X            A     2       Y
A     2       Y            B     1       Z
B     1       Z
B     1       Z
B     1       Z
```

Hugh Thank you for any Help or Ideas! : )

Ich dachte an full_join mit dplyr kann es aber nicht richtig umsetzen.

Ich bin leider noch keine R Expertin. Falls jemand von euch eine Idee hat und mir helfen kann wäre ich sehr sehr dankbar.

Viele Liebe Grüße

Comment: Hi @MaryJule, Could you please ask your question in English. Also please share your data using `dput(DATA1)` to make it reproduceable.

Comment: Hi Quinten, 
i will try, i hope you can get my Problem. 

I have two Dataframes and i want to Merge those with an doppel Key. Data1 is having more rows than Data 2. I want to add the Columns from DATA2 to DATA1. 
For all Rows, witch are more in DATA1, but is having the same Keys i want to copy the Values from DATA2. 
I hope you can understand what i mean. Thanks for youre Response! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `left_join` from `dplyr` and select multiple columns `by` which you want to join. You can use the following code:

```
DATA1 <- data.frame(key1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                    key2 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))

DATA2 <- data.frame(key1 = c("A", "A", "B"),
                    key2 = c(1, 2, 1),
                    XXX = c("X", "Y", "Z"))

library(dplyr)
DATA_COMBINED <- left_join(DATA1, DATA2, by = c("key1", "key2"))
DATA_COMBINED
```

Output:

```
  key1 key2 XXX
1    A    1   X
2    A    1   X
3    A    2   Y
4    B    1   Z
5    B    1   Z
6    B    1   Z
```